# How to restrict a application to install on SD card?

Tags: android

I am developing one application and i want to force a user to install this application in internal storage.Application can not be installed on SD Card

Any Suggestion and idea will be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check `android:installLocation` in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html

EDIT: since from question in title i thought you want to force user to install on SD card

Answer (score 2):

U no read docs

> However, if you're certain that your application should never be installed on the external storage, then you should make this clear by declaring android:installLocation with a value of "internalOnly"

from http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html

Answer (score 1):

In Your Mainfest file do this
For SD Card

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.emx.jamalert"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal">
```

For Internal Memory

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.emx.jamalert"
    android:installLocation="Internal">
```